# Ruby: replacement part include $1 $2 $3 and saved in a variable, but interpolation doesn't happen when using gsub

Tags: ruby, gsub, string-interpolation

(a) the codes I wrote.

```
$str = '909090 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 12345678 aa bb 12345678 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 22 33 123456 FE 89'
puts $str
$str.gsub!(/\s+/, '')

search_1  = 'aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 (\S{8} aa bb \S{8} aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 22 33 \S{6}) (FF|FE) (89)'
puts search_1
search_1.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
replace_1 = '11 22 33 44 55 66 77 $1 $2 $3'
puts replace_1
replace_1.gsub!(/\s+/, '')

repls_1 = [
  [search_1, replace_1],
]


repls_1.each do |x|
  abc = $str.gsub(Regexp.new(x[0])) {
    x[1]
  }
  puts abc
end
```

(2) script running results

```
  909090 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 12345678 aa bb 12345678 aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 22 33 123456 FE 89
  aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 (\S{8} aa bb \S{8} aa bb cc dd ee ff 00 11 22 33 \S{6}) (FF|FE) (89)
  11 22 33 44 55 66 77 $1 $2 $3

  90909011223344556677$1$2$3
```

The interpolation for $1, $2, $3 doesn't happen, is there way to solve it? Thanks.

(i) I don't want use \1 \2 \3, but $1 $2 $3)

(ii) There're more than one patterns, here only one example

(iii) matched parts numbers is not fixed, here is $1$2$3, other case is possible, such as ...$1...$2...$3...$5..., hope the codes can cover this variation on both captured parts number and position.

Comment: Would you mind adding what output you actually expect?

Comment: $1: 12345678aabb12345678aabbccddeeff00112233123456 
 $2: FE
 $3: 89

 So the output I want is: 9090901122334455667712345678aabb12345678aabbccddeeff00112233123456FE89

Comment: Bridge, when readers ask for clarification it's generally better to edit your question than to respond in comments. That keeps the question self-contained. More generally, readers should not be expected to read the comments to understand the question. Also, whenever you give an example always show the desired return value.

Comment: If  you write `replace_1 = '11 22 33 44 55 66 77 \1 \2 \3'.delete(' ') #=> "11223344556677\\1\\2\\3"` (note `\\1\\2\\3` rather than `$1$2$3`), `rgx = Regexp.new(search_1.delete(' ')) #=> 
/aabbccddeeff00(\S{8}aabb\S{8}aabbccddeeff00112233\S{6})(FF|FE)(89)/` then 
`$str.gsub(rgx, replace_1) #=> "9090901122334455667712345678aabb12345678aabbccddeeff00112233123456FE89"` produces the desired result, but you want use `$1, $2,...` rather than `\1, \2,...`. Why? Incidentally, there is no point to  writing `repls_1.each do |x|...` since `repls_1` contains only a single element (a two-element array).

Comment: @Cary, many thanks for your help check my question.

Comment: @Cary  “since repls_1 contains only a single element”， this is just an example, in fact, there're several different patterns, so I put them into two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, the gsub method does not support $1, $2, $3 etc. for interpolation in the replacement string. However you can use them in a block given to gsub as given below. Try modifying this code.

```
repls_1.each do |x|
  abc = $str.gsub(Regexp.new(x[0])) {
    '11223344556677' + $1 + $2 + $3
  }
  puts abc
end
```

**Edit**

$~ is a special variable that holds the MatchData object for the last match. The captures method returns an array of all the groups in the match and join concatenates them together. This will work no matter how many groups your regex has. So here is the code.

```
repls_1.each do |x|
  abc = $str.gsub(Regexp.new(x[0])) {
    '11223344556677' + $~.captures.join
  }
  puts abc
end
```

Comment: But there're many patterns(another pattern may have $4, $5 ......), is there way can work without fixed the $N numbers?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer, have a look at it. $~ holds the necessary data for you.

Comment: @BridgeIC See the above updated answer.

Comment: Many thanks fist, Rajagopalan.
 The '11223344556677' is also not fixed, it should be different in other patterns. And Also the position for $1, $2, $3...  is not fixed in different patterns. So I want collect all patterns in array repls_1, and just use x[1] replace x[0] with interpolation for $N, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, seems same output as 90909011223344556677$1$2$3 with eval.

Comment: I thought that would work. Okay, can you try this one? `abc = $str.gsub(Regexp.new(x[0])) { x[1].gsub(/\$(\d+)/) { $~[$1.to_i] } }` ?

Comment: Good idea. The output is now 909090112233445566771, seems still a little issue, would you help have a look?

Comment: sorry, I don't know, someone else might help you.

Comment: @ Rajagopalan
 Fixed $N at end of replacement, seems use your code works now, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't want use \1 \2 \3, but $1 $2 $3

You *could* dynamically replace `$1`, `$2`, `$3` with their respective capture from the match before:

```
repls_1.each do |pattern, replacement|
  puts $str.gsub(Regexp.new(pattern)) {
    match_data = $~
    replacement.gsub(/\$(\d)/) { match_data[$1.to_i] }
  }
end
```

However, this is basically re-inventing the wheel because `gsub` has built-in replacement via `\1`, `\2`, `\3` back-references.

It would be much easier to simply replace `$1`, `$2`, `$3` with `\1`, `\2`, `\3` to get a replacement string that's compatible with `gsub`. Since you want to keep your `$`-notation, you can perform this replacement at runtime, e.g. via [`tr`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
repls_1.each do |pattern, replacement|
  gsub_replacement = replacement.tr('$', '\\')
  puts $str.gsub(Regexp.new(pattern), gsub_replacement)
end
```

You could also store the `gsub`-adjusted replacement string and an actual pattern in your `repls_1` array already:

```
# create actual pattern and adjust replacement string
repls_1.map! { |a, b| [Regexp.new(a), b.tr('$', '\\')] }
```

This way, you don't have to repeat the adjustments every time and the replacement becomes even simpler (and faster):

```
repls_1.each do |pattern, replacement|
  puts $str.gsub(pattern, replacement)
end
```

Note that the code above replaces *all* `$` with `\`. For a more sophisticated replacement, you could use another regex, e.g. to take a following digit into account:

```
gsub_replacement = replacement.gsub(/\$(?=\d)/, '\\')
```

Comment: Many thanks, Stefan, I'll study it.

Comment: Dear Stefan,  yes, seems \N is better way for gsub interpolation， your solution is very good also. I'm sorry seems can only accept one answer as solution as rule. Anyway, many thanks for your help and guide.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Rajagopalan's code (after study, put all $N at the end is fine, then this solution works.):

```
abc = $str.gsub(Regexp.new(x[0])) {
  s2 = $~.captures.join
  s1 = x[1].split(/\$/)[0]
  s1 + s2
}
```

Comment: `x` (presumably as defined in the question) is here undefined.